# New to Google Storage, Cannot create a storage bucket as storage admin

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

As stated in the title I am new to using Google storage, well the entire google cloud ecosystem really.  I've been using the speech-to-text api for a number of years with my phone system, and in the latest version I'm required to create a storage bucket, and upload voicemails for transcription.

I've assigned my iam user the "Storage Admin" role along with other required roles [user permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3L5S.png), when I open the storage browser I am met with the error "Additional permissions required to list buckets in this project. Ask a project owner to grant you 'storage.buckets.list' permission." [list permission error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgGxn.png)and when I try to create a bucket I am met with "Additional permissions required to create this bucket. Ask a project owner to grant you 'storage.buckets.create' permission and try again."[Create bucket error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9c7W.png).

I guess my question is what am I missing? Are there other hidden permissions these roles don't grant my user?  Does applying the roles take hours to propagate and apply? did I assign the roles in the wrong place or at the wrong level?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this is not your issue, I only this bring up because you stated you're new to the google cloud ecosystem.

Have you tried accessing your bucket in a private browser tab/window? I've bumped into numerous confusing issues because I'm logged into a Google account already in a browser that's different than the one I use for GCP (even when the it looks like I'm using the correct account in the cloud console UX).